Trying to read a specific line in c++ but nothing is displaying anything
So i'm writing some test code for a bigger project that will display specific data when a code and address has been entered, but currently nothing is running and i'm not getting any output at all.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
    std::ifstream testdata; testdata.open("testdata.csv");
    std::string line, csvitem;
    int linenum = 0;
    int linenumsought = 2;

    if(testdata.is_open()){
        while (testdata){
            linenum++;

            if(linenum == linenumsought){
                std::cout << line << '\n';
                std::istringstream myline(line);

                while(getline(myline, csvitem, ',')){
                    std::cout << csvitem << '\n';
                }
            }
        }
        testdata.close();
    }

    return 0;
}

Im really tired and most likely have just missed something small lol, but if someone could help on why im not getting any display at all from my csv file that'd be very much appreciated.
House,111111,2046
House2,222222,2222

csv file ^^
Whenever I have managed to get an output, it runs infinitely creating lines in the terminal. That or it will simply say "permission denied"

Your code misses reading line from the file. while (testdata){  probably should be while (std::getline(testdata,line)) {

Side note: get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing std::ifstream testdata; testdata.open("testdata.csv"); to std::ifstream testdata("testdata.csv");. Also, you don’t have to call testdata.close(); the destructor will do that.

Style note: you may wish to test if the file is not open, print an error message and immediately return with an error code. You can then proceed under the knowledge that the file is open and unindent the remainder of your code a level.

@drescherjm tysm that fixed it lol, genuinely tysm

Your code misses reading the file into the line variable.
A simple correction would be to replace:
   while (testdata){

With the following:
   while (std::getline(testdata,line)) {

This change not only reads the line one at a time but ends the loop when the read failed which will happen at the end of the file or if there was some type of error.
You may also remove this line:
        testdata.close();

The destructor for testdata will close the file for you so you need not close it yourself.
Taking the example 1 step further instead of reading the lines we can skip ahead n lines:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>

bool readCSVLine(std::ifstream &inputFile, size_t nLine)
{
    if (!inputFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: File not open!\n";
        return false;
    }

    // Skip the next n lines using 0 based indexing. 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nLine; ++i)
    {
        // Ignore the next line. Here we ignore the maximum amount of characters 
        // up until the newline delimiter is found.
        if (!inputFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'))
        {
            // If this returns false we could not read the line.
            std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not read line " << i << '\n';
            return false;
        }
    }

    // We skipped ahead now read the line.
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
        std::istringstream myline(line);
        std::string csvitem;
        while (std::getline(myline, csvitem, ','))
        {
            std::cout << csvitem << '\n';
        }
        return true;
    }

    std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not read line " << nLine << '\n';
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream testdata("testdata.csv");
    unsigned int linenumsought = 2;
    return readCSVLine(testdata, linenumsought) ? 0 : 1;
}

Note that the above code uses 0 based indexing so the third line is what would be printed in the example. For 1 based indexing you could change this line: for (size_t i = 0; i < nLine; ++i) to for (size_t i = 1; i < nLine; ++i)

To take this a step further, you can use testdata.ignore() to skip unwanted lines until the desired line is reached, and then call std::getline() just 1 time to read that line. No point in wasting memory reading lines that will just get discarded. Also, you should terminate the loop once the desired line is reached, since subsequent lines are being ignored.
